# IE11 Pseudo-element animation is not working properly

Tags: html, css, css-animations, internet-explorer-11, pseudo-element

While building a loader icon, I noticed odd behavior in IE11 compared to Chrome, using this animation:

```css
@keyframes loader-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translateX(-1.6rem);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

The element correctly translates to the side at first, but then shifts super far before translating back. This only behaves this way in IE11 (works fine in Chrome/Firefox), and only on a pseudo-element (`::after`).

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26xpfh5k/7/) (or below code snippet) for an example. The top dot is a `span`, which works fine, the bottom dot is an `::after` element, which behaves weirdly.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.splash {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

@keyframes loader-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-1.6rem);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.2rem;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 3.2rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.loader span {
  animation: loader-2 1.5s ease infinite;
  background: #024;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 1.6rem;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1.6rem;
}

.loader div::after {
  animation: loader-2 1.5s ease infinite;
  background: #024;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1.6rem;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3.2rem;
  width: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <div class="loader">
    <span></span>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to work around this by not using pseudo-elements of course, but I would still like to know what causes this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation and transition for pseudo-elements is not supported by IE11, check here:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_after_animation_and_transition_support

Comment: Interesting that it works to some degree then, considering it says it has absolutely no support.

Answer (score -1):

To work around this issue, you can try to use ID for the div and write CSS for it and avoid using pseudo.

Modified code:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.splash {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

@keyframes loader-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-1.6rem);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.2rem;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 3.2rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.loader span {
  animation: loader-2 1.5s ease infinite;
  background: #024;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 1.6rem;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1.6rem;
}

.loader #abc {
  animation: loader-2 1.5s ease infinite;
  background: #024;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1.6rem;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3.2rem;
  width: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <div class="loader">
    <span></span>
    <div id="abc"></div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

Comment: As I said I know how to work around the issue, I just wanted to know where the problem came from.